# How to return http request data

Tags: angular

I want to return http request data. I have a function, but code editor about "data" variable sais.
"Variable might not have been initialized" ().

```
getData() {
    let data;
    this.http.get(this.url + 'user', {headers: this.headers})
      .subscribe(dt => {
        data = dt;
      });
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I use Web Storm. Function returns undefined.

Comment: In comments below you are mentioning canActivate router guard. Please share your code for that guard. That being said you can simple return the get() as long as you type the get correctly to return Observable<boolean>

Answer (score 2):

Since you are subscribing Observable in the function, it returns `data` immediately before getting the response.

You need to subscribe where you need it.

```ts
getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'user', {headers: this.headers});
}
```

```ts
getData().subscribe(dt => {
  let data = dt;
  // Use the data below
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to return variable "data".

Comment: @HaykNikoghosyan That is not possible because it's an asynchronous operation. At least you should use `async` and `await` .